# I am getting error #1329 - No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error in the following code below. The error is #1329 - No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed. What exactly does this mean and what is it that i am doing incorrectly?
Thanks

```
create procedure cursorproc(OUT p_out DECIMAL(10,2)) begin

   declare l_salary, l_total DECIMAL(10,2);

   declare cur_1 cursor for select line_distance from elements;
       open cur_1;

   set l_total = 0;

   loop

      fetch cur_1 into l_salary;

         set l_total = l_total + l_salary;
         end loop;

   close cur_1;

   set p_out = l_total;

end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should a `DECLARE HANDLER` for the cursor when no more data is found: in [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/declare-handlers.html) you can find about how to do so.

Use

```
DECLARE handler_type HANDLER FOR condition_value[,...] sp_statement
```

Where handler type is one of: `CONTINUE, EXIT or UNDO`

Condition value is one of `SQLSTATE [VALUE] sqlstate_value | condition_name | SQLWARNING  | NOT FOUND | SQLEXCEPTION | mysql_error_code`. In this case `NOT FOUND` is what you're (maybe) looking for.

So your code would become something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cursorproc(OUT p_out DECIMAL(10,2)) 
BEGIN
   DECLARE l_salary, l_total DECIMAL(10,2);
   DECLARE _continue INT DEFAULT 0;

   DECLARE cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT line_distance FROM elements;   
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET _continue =1;
   OPEN cur_1;
   SET l_total = 0;
   REPEAT
      FETCH cur_1 INTO l_salary;
      SET l_total = l_total + l_salary;
      UNTIL _continue = 1;
   END REPEAT;
   CLOSE cur_1;
   SET p_out = l_total;
END;
```

Also review the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/declare-handlers.html) for further information.

Comment: thnx but still not able to implement can u plz help me out....many thanks in advance

Comment: Don't think the `;` after `UNTIL _continue = 1` is allowed

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the same, in essence, as [How to get rid of "Error 1329: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463283/how-to-get-rid-of-error-1329-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-process), where I provided the "found_rows()" solution: http://tinky2jed.wordpress.com/technical-stuff/mysql/mysql-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-how-to-code-for-it/