# MYSQL trigger generates a 1329 error

Tags: mysql, triggers, warnings

I have two tables,  one that list entries and another that has results.

I am trying to create a After trigger on the entries table that creates a corresponding record in the results table, IF all of the entry information for that record is complete. The column fleet is not NULL if the results table should be created.

```
IF (NEW.fleet IS NOT NULL) THEN

INSERT INTO race_results (race_id,yr,race_num,owner_id,checked_in,flt)VALUES(NEW.race_id,NEW.yr,NEW.race_num,NEW.owner_id,"N",NEW.fleet)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flt =NEW.fleet;

END IF
```

This code runs fine except when it runs on a row with NEW.fleet equals NULL it throws a #1329 error.

Thanks in advance.

Based on the input this is my latest try. Still not working
Table clubs is just a different table to do a successful select at the end.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE clb INT(10);
declare exit handler for not found

IF (NEW.fleet IS NOT NULL) THEN

INSERT INTO race_results (race_id,yr,race_num,owner_id,checked_in,flt)
VALUES(NEW.race_id,NEW.yr,NEW.race_num,NEW.owner_id,"N",NEW.fleet)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flt =NEW.fleet;

END IF;
SELECT club_id INTO clb from clubs WHERE club_id=1;
END
```

Comment: This might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957751/i-am-getting-error-1329-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-processed-i

Answer (score 0):

"Without using Handler"

I had the null pointer problem when I used the following query in stored procedure...

```
Select col1 into Var from table1;
```

Instead I changed it to

```
Set var = (select col1 from table1);
```

here it doesn't thro as fatal error...

Try to store the updated (new.fleet) value in a variable and then use it .. hope it should solve.

Comment: Tried it that didn't work,  been playing around with Handlers and can seem to get that working either.