# MySQL 1329 Error No Data - Zero rows fetched

Tags: mysql

I have searched SO, for similar and I found one other posting similar to this and I followed what I thought was the follow up but I'm still seeing a problem.

I have also been sifting through the MySQL manuals, and what I have here looks like it is correct.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`perimUser`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `assignLOBId`()
BEGIN
    declare id, done INT default 0;
    declare name VarChar(45);

    declare lobCursor Cursor for Select idLineOfBusiness as id, name from LineOfBusiness;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;

    OPEN lobCursor;

    my_loop: LOOP 
        FETCH lobCursor INTO id, name;

            IF done = 1 THEN
                CLOSE lobCursor;
                LEAVE my_loop;
            END IF; 

            insert into test values (id, name);
            UPDATE medium set idLOB = id where LOB = name;
            UPDATE low set idLOB = id where LOB = name;

    End LOOP my_loop;

END
```

I have run the Query that I"m using for the cursor and it does return 13 rows.  Tables medium and low are full of data about 600 rows in each.  the LOB match values in the LOB column of each.  The values that were used to create the ones in lineofbusiness were generated from medium and low.

The goal here is to use this pattern a number of times as I work to normalized the data in medium and low.  Otherwise I'd take the short cut and create a bunch of manual update statements.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463283/how-to-get-rid-of-error-1329-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure why your cursor isn't working as expected (you don't say whether your `test` table is populated with the results that you expect?), but it appears to me your procedure is simply implementing a multiple-table `UPDATE` (so can probably be entirely replaced with the following):

```
UPDATE LineOfBusiness
  LEFT JOIN medium ON LineOfBusiness.name = medium.LOB
  LEFT JOIN low    ON LineOfBusiness.name =    low.LOB
   SET medium.idLOB = LineOfBusiness.idLineOfBusiness
     ,    low.idLOB = LineOfBusiness.idLineOfBusiness
```