# 1329 No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have changed this stored procedure many times and still keep getting the same error.  I know I am getting rows back because I tested the cursor select separately.  I have read other similar issues on this site but I don't seem to have the same fix.

```
DECLARE iDone INTEGER(10) DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE userID INTEGER(10);
DECLARE creditRemaining INTEGER(10);

DECLARE column_cur CURSOR FOR
     SELECT `userID`, `creditRemaining` FROM `access` 
     WHERE (`dateExpire`>=now() OR `isRenewed`=1) and `descriptionShort`='Subscription';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET iDone=1;

SET userID = 0;
SET creditRemaining = 0;
OPEN column_cur;
LOOP1: LOOP   

   FETCH column_cur INTO userID, creditRemaining;
   IF iDone = 1
       THEN
          LEAVE LOOP1;
   END IF;
   -- SELECT userID, creditRemaining;
   UPDATE `users` SET `saveCount`=creditRemaining, `searchCount`=6000 WHERE `ID`=userID;

END LOOP LOOP1;
CLOSE column_cur;
```

Comment: Never solved the specific question but the following did was I was trying to do with the procedure:

    UPDATE `access` a JOIN users u ON u.ID=a.userID SET u.saveCount=a.creditRemaining, u.searchCount=6000
        WHERE (a.`dateExpire`>=now() OR a.`isRenewed`=1) and a.`descriptionShort`='Subscription';

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of more, except for the fact you already have a HANDLER declared.  In another `Error 1329` question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690018/7358209) from @DanJGer pointed out a note in the docs:

> Before MySQL 5.6.3, if a statement that generates a warning or error causes a condition handler to be invoked, the handler may not clear the diagnostic area. This might lead to the appearance that the handler was not invoked. The following discussion demonstrates the issue and provides a workaround.

That's likely the problem you're encountering.