# Warning 1329 no data fetched

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```sql
delimiter ;;

create procedure cd3(out var int)
begin
   declare finished int default 0;
   declare cur cursor for select id from a;
   declare continue handler for not found set finished=1;
   open cur;
   curloop:loop
      fetch cur into var;
      if finished then
         leave curloop;
      end if;
   end loop curloop;
   close cur;
end;;

call cd3(@var);
```

Comment: Does "select id from a" return any records at all?

Comment: no,only the warning 1329 is recived

Comment: Abhik, instead of creating a new question. You can edit your question here as it is the same problem but you have tried different code. Dont create mulitple questions based on same problem.

Comment: The following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11804/1) everything seems to work as expected. I do not see the message that you show.

Comment: I tried your previous code but it did not work.Now I'll try the select statement before the end of the loop as you told,I think it will help me out.Anyway,thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning provided by MySQL. They can be a bit confusing, i suggest you read up on it: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5./en/show-warnings.html

I would use this approach instead

```
declare v_var VARCHAR(200); <-- if that whats it expected to be
open cur;

-- create a loop

repeat_cur: LOOP
FETCH cur INTO var;
-- checks if it is done
if finished then
    LEAVE repeat_cur;
end if;

// DO THE WORK

END LOOP;
close cur;
```

Im not sure since var is a expected out parameter. You can declare `var` as a variable and work with it, otherwise just skip the declare line i wrote.

Check out this page: [How to get rid of "Error 1329: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463283/how-to-get-rid-of-error-1329-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-process) , he had the same problem, and was solved by adding a simple select statement into var.

If above doesnt work, try adding this before the end of the loop.

```
SELECT 'var' INTO var;
```