# Java - MySql Stored Procedure "No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed"

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

in my web application, While I am trying to retrieve data for saved data and select box through ResultSet and I got the below error on calling the following procedure. Please give your valuable solutions thanks

Error Found :

```
  Error: java.sql.SQLException: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:920)
    at com.schoolmanager.util.StoreProcHandler.accessStoredProcedure(StoreProcHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:187)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Java:

method from StoreProcHandlerClass :

```
     public ResultSet accessStoredProcedure(List<Object> parameters,
        String procedureCalled) throws CommunicationsException {
    ResultSet rSet = null;
    int noofParameters = parameters.size();
    try {

        System.out.println("parameters " + parameters);
        System.out.println("Procedure  Elements " +  "{call " + procedureCalled +  "("
                + getGenList(parameters.size()) + ")}");
        callStat = connect.prepareCall( "{call " + procedureCalled +  "("
                + getGenList(parameters.size()) + ")}");

        for (int i = 1; i <= noofParameters; i++) {
            Object obj = parameters.get(i-1);

            if (obj.toString().contains("Types")) {
                callStat.registerOutParameter(i, Types.VARCHAR);
            } else {
                callStat.setObject(i, obj);
            }
        }
        callStat.execute();
        rSet = callStat.getResultSet();
        if(rSet != null){
            rSet.next();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        finally {
        try {

                logger.info("Procedure Executed from ASP ="+procedureCalled);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return rSet;

}
```

Error Part :

```
    List<Object> parameters = null;
    ResultSet rSet = null;
    Connection con = (Connection) request.getAttribute("accessConnect");
    int noOfCols = 4;
    String qMsg = null;
    System.out.println("session.getAttribute " + session.getAttribute("userType"));
    parameters = 
        new ArrayList<Object>(
                        Arrays.asList(session.getAttribute("userMail"), 
                session.getAttribute("userType"), 
                Types.VARCHAR, 
                Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, 
                Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR ));
          StoreProcHandler sph = new StoreProcHandler(con);
          rSet = sph.accessStoredProcedure(parameters,
                                 "GET_USER_PROFILE");  
if (rSet != null)   
{  
    rSet.beforeFirst();  
    rSet.last();  
    System.out.println("rSet row " + rSet.getRow());  
}
```

Mysql Stored Procedure :

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`user_name`@`%` PROCEDURE `GET_USER_PROFILE`(
            IN p_user_id VARCHAR(150),
            IN p_role VARCHAR(150),
            OUT p_user_data VARCHAR(200),
            OUT p_city VARCHAR(150),
            OUT p_state VARCHAR(150),
            OUT p_country VARCHAR(150),
            OUT q_Msg VARCHAR(150))
  BEGIN

   DECLARE available INT DEFAULT 0;

   DECLARE CUR_CITY CURSOR for SELECT CITY FROM COUNTRIES;
   DECLARE CUR_STATE CURSOR for SELECT STATE FROM COUNTRIES;
   DECLARE CUR_COUNTRY CURSOR for SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRIES;
   DECLARE CUR_U_DATA CURSOR FOR SELECT * from STAFF_PROFILE WHERE EMAIL = p_user_id AND ROLE = p_role;

SELECT COUNT(EMAIL) INTO available FROM STAFF_PROFILE WHERE EMAIL = p_user_id AND ROLE = p_role;


CALL sql_logger('user_profile', p_city);

OPEN CUR_CITY;
OPEN CUR_STATE;
OPEN CUR_COUNTRY;

get_list: LOOP
    FETCH CUR_CITY INTO p_city;
    FETCH CUR_STATE INTO p_state;
    FETCH CUR_COUNTRY INTO p_country;
END LOOP get_list;

IF(available=1) THEN
     OPEN CUR_U_DATA;
     get_data: LOOP
     FETCH CUR_U_DATA INTO p_user_data;
     END LOOP get_data;
else
     SET q_Msg = 'USER_LOGGED_FIRST';
END IF;

END
```

Comment: Post your java code also.

Comment: @Karthikeyan posted pls check !!

Comment: Post the other code that appears to be the cause of the exception (`com.schoolmanager.util.StoreProcHandler`).

Comment: Maybe try a dummy statement instead of `SET q_Msg = ...` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6761925/3080094)?

Comment: @randxy OK, could you put in an answer (to your own question) exactly what you did to solve the issue so that others may learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Now i found the solution for this issue, I got confused the result set with OUT parameter and also found the following way of code for java.sql.ResultSet

java Code portion: (ADDED AFTER calling procedure from CallableStatement)

```
        callStat.execute();

        int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = null;
        int resultRow = 1;
        int col = 1;
        boolean result = callStat.execute();

        while(result){
            ResultSet rs = callStat.getResultSet();
            col=1;
            while(rs.next()){
                metaData = rs.getMetaData();
                String colName = metaData.getColumnName(1);   // column to be retrieved

                String value = (String) rs.getObject(colName);;
                System.out.println(value);
                col++;
            }
            resultRow++;
            rs.close();
            result = callStat.getMoreResults(CallableStatement.CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT);
        }
```

MYSQL Stored procedure :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user_name`@`%` PROCEDURE `GET_USER_PROFILE`(
            IN p_user_id VARCHAR(150),
            IN p_role VARCHAR(150),
            OUT q_Msg VARCHAR(150))
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT state FROM countries ;
SELECT DISTINCT city  FROM countries ;
SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY COUNTRY ASC;



SET q_Msg = 'EXECUTED';
```