# Error code 1329, SQL state 02000: No data - for a function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql 5.0.27. I had written the following function.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION getDebit (trip1 INT UNSIGNED)

RETURNS DOUBLE

BEGIN
DECLARE oldName DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(amt,0)) INTO oldName 
       FROM  expenses where head IN(SELECT distinct name 
       FROM head where payType='Debit') AND trip=trip1 GROUP BY trip;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

RETURN oldName;

END

DELIMITER ;
```

It gives the error `Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;END' at line 11` .

Please help me.

Comment: It gives error when the resultset is empty

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463283/how-to-get-rid-of-error-1329-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-process

Comment: @NoDisplayName,How to apply that solution for this function.

Comment: Seems worth noting that you're using an unsupported version of MySQL. The oldest active version is 5.5. You might want to upgrade.

Comment: @Tieson T,is it works fine if i upgraded to mysql5.5

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake there:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(amt,0)) INTO oldName 
   FROM  expenses where head IN(SELECT distinct name 
   FROM head where payType='Debit') AND trip=trip1 GROUP BY trip;
```

This call must be used after ALL declarations.
Error occurs when mysql see "DECLARE" after "SELECT"
Also, you MUST declare variable "done"

Maybe you mean:

```
/* Add this */
DECLARE done int;

/* Your code*/
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

/* Add this */
SET done  = 0;

/* your code next */
SUM(COALESCE(amt,0)) INTO oldName 
       FROM  expenses where head IN(SELECT distinct name 
       FROM head where payType='Debit') AND trip=trip1 GROUP BY trip;

return oldName;
```

BUT!!!
Your declaration of continue handler is useless.

SUM() will be return value always.
If nothing was found it will be 0.

And "done" will never changed