# How to skip to next iteration if no results are returned in SELECT statement in Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, continue

I have a case where I `SELECT` rows from one table and `INSERT` them to another table. However, I get `Error: 1329 SQLSTATE: 02000` if the `SELECT` statement doesn't return any row. Can I do something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP()
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND;
   BEGIN
      ITERATE
   END
   BEGIN 
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM table1;
      OPEN cur1; 
      read_loop: LOOP
         FETCH cur1 INTO var1;
         INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT c1 FROM table3)
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur1;
   END;
```

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the `INSERT INTO [table] (...) SELECT (...) FROM [table]` syntax ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html )  then you don't need to use a stored procedure with a CURSOR.

Comment: @RaymondNijland the actual SP is more complex than the code I gave. I do need the LOOP.

Comment: ITERATE can appear only within LOOP, REPEAT, and WHILE statements. ITERATE means “start the loop again.” - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/iterate.html I don't see how this would be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of "Error 1329: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463283/how-to-get-rid-of-error-1329-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-process)