# How to add salary from two tables in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add the salary from two tables in stored procedure on the basis of id column:

**DDl:**

```
create table salary1 (id varchar(20), salary varchar(20));
create table salary2 (id varchar(20), salary varchar(20));
```

**DML:**

```
insert into salary1 values('1', '100');
insert into salary1 values('2', '200');
insert into salary2 values('1', '10');
insert into salary2 values('2', '10');
```

**Database:** mysql

**Output should like this**:

```
id   total_sal
1     110
2     210
```

My stored procedure look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE totalSal()
BEGIN
  DECLARE tbl1_id  varchar(30);
  DECLARE tbl1_sal varchar(30);
  DECLARE tbl2_id  varchar(30);
  DECLARE tbl2_sal  varchar(30);
  DECLARE total_sal varchar(30);


  DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT *  FROM salary1;
  DECLARE c2 CURSOR FOR SELECT *  FROM salary2;
   -- Open first cursor
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO tbl1_id, tbl1_sal;

      -- Open second cursor
      OPEN c2;
      LOOP
         FETCH c2 INTO tbl2_id, tbl2_sal;
         IF tbl1_id = tbl2_id THEN
                  set total_sal := tbl1_sal + tbl2_sal;    
               ELSE
                   set total_sal := tbl_sal;                           
               END IF;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE c2;

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c1;
end $$
```

It got's successfully compiled, but when i am running the procedure i am getting the below error:
**ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed**
I have also used the `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;` in my procedure. but still my problem is unresolved.
If someone can solve this problem in oracle, that would also help me.

**Note :** I cannot perform `join` operation on these tables. Because of a few performance issues.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @Phil Yes, mean output should contain 'id' and 'total_salary'

Comment: What kinds of performance issues you met? I don't think your approach is better than 'join'.

Comment: @DHARMINDER - Sorry, couldn't get formatting to work. For the output you're looking for id 1 and 2 to be on separate lines correct?

Comment: @Sphinx, table contains millions of records, and there is many more calculation we are performing

Comment: @Phil Yes, you are right.

Comment: Your logic doesn't seem correct. I believe you are trying to loop through the second query more than the number of times you should be. You need to use the id from the first table to select only those ids from the second table instead of selecting from the whole table again.

Comment: Can you sum by ID then do some addition? This seems overly complex unless I am missing something here.

Comment: @clinomaniac Yes, i am trying to traverse the second loop on the basis of first loop. Don't where i am going wrong in logic wise. But without using join how can i do this ? Can you please suggest?

Comment: @DHARMINDER I have posted an answer. Cannot fit the procedure in comments. :)

Comment: @DHARMINDER, try to implement with one sql command, then execute [Explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) to figure out which factors cause the performance issue. (you can add the explain result to the question, then we can help you from that on)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
Using collection and only one iteration of 2 loop
```

You should consider to fix your performance issue on `join`. Performing loop is slower than a set base approach in most case.

If I follow your logic, what you realy want is to loop trough all the salary2 table for each salary1 row in order to found the right ID => millions of loop.

You can consider doing 2 separated loop and store data inside and indexed array. ( the key will be the tlb1_id).
If the key exist : sum the salary values, if not exist insert it inside the array.

At the end of the procedure, just select the array as table.

**Solution 2:**

```
Using a join on integer indexed columns
```

1. you can add a new integer column on each table
2. Populate this column with the casted value of the ID column
3. Add an index on these columns on each tables
4. After that you will be able to perform a join

Have a look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c445de/1  , it can be time consuming to perform theses step and disk space consumuming to add a new columns and indexes but the join operation may be faster than before.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please advise any feasible solution to get the desired output without joining the tables?

Comment: What makes you sure that nested, looping cursors would be faster than a JOIN?

Comment: @JacobH, i wrote the opposite of your sentence, and i said : "in most case".

Comment: Yes I'm agreeing with you. The OP is convinced that looping is faster (they made like 6 comments so far saying that). I am just curious why. I'm also not convinced this is all the code, OP seems to be saying there is additional code. I'm almost positive these errors are both a) red herrings and b) alluding to XY problem.

Comment: @JacobH, I am curious why, toooo. Even Performing loop (especially millions) is required, I prefer to pulling data out then calculate in one script (Python-Pandas, or Excel-VBA etc), at least, we don't need to care the locks for the millions of records.

Comment: His joins are probably atrocious performance because they are using strings for ID's tbh. Like I said, there is nearly 100% chance this is an XY problem, in my mind.

Comment: @DHARMINDER I updated my answer with a way to improve perfomance of the join approach. Assuming you can modify the model

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this... I have moved the second cursor inside the loop so that it only goes over the id's from table 1. This should help the logic for the procedure but still I would recommend trying to figure out how to fix the join to get the results as that seems like an easier way and should be much faster if done correctly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE totalSal()
BEGIN
  DECLARE tbl1_id  varchar(30);
  DECLARE tbl1_sal varchar(30);
  DECLARE tbl2_id  varchar(30);
  DECLARE tbl2_sal  varchar(30);
  DECLARE total_sal varchar(30);

  DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT *  FROM salary1;

   -- Open first cursor
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO tbl1_id, tbl1_sal;

      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_rowcount FROM salary2 WHERE id = tbl1_id;
      IF v_rowcount > 0 THEN

      Begin
      DECLARE c2 CURSOR FOR SELECT *  FROM salary2 WHERE id = tbl1_id;
      -- Open second cursor
      OPEN c2;
      LOOP
         FETCH c2 INTO tbl2_id, tbl2_sal;
         IF tbl1_id = tbl2_id THEN
                  set total_sal := tbl1_sal + tbl2_sal;    
               ELSE
                   set total_sal := tbl_sal;                           
               END IF;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE c2;
      END IF;
   END
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c1;
end $$
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i have tried the procedure updated by you, but using this i ma facing the below error
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE c2 CURSOR FOR SELECT *  FROM salary2 WHERE id = tbl1_id;

Comment: DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements

Comment: Updated based on comments.

Comment: Logicaly it can works if your database can handle millions of queries on table salary2

Comment: I don't think it is one good idea. it must be slower than 'implementation with one sql command (join or subquery). it will cause bigger performance issue.

Comment: @clinomaniac Thanks, procedure got compiled successfully. But while calling the procedure, its throwing the below error:
ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Comment: @DHARMINDER, check this URL [ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463283/how-to-get-rid-of-error-1329-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-process)

Comment: @Sphinx I have checked this link earlier also and by using this, i have added the 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;' in my procedure, but by doing the, it is throwing below compile time error:
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'done'

Comment: @DHARMINDER done is a variable used in that example. You don't have it in your example. You need to see what you need to do in your example.

Comment: @clinomaniac Oh ok, actually i am not aware of how to use this in my procedure. Can you please help me to implement this ?

Comment: @clinomaniac I have compiled the updated procedure but it throws below error:

ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: v_rowcount , then have declared 'v_rowcount' variable by doing 'DECLARE v_rowcount varchar(30);'
and again when i compiled, it throws below error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF;
   END
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
end' at line 34

Comment: You can declare that variable at the start with all the other declares.

Comment: @DHARMINDER, swap 'End if' with the following 'END'.

Comment: @Sphinx I didn't get your point. Can you please explain it further?

Comment: @clinomaniac Yes, i have declared this variable, but after doing this i ma getting an error
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF; END END LOOP; CLOSE c1;

Comment: @DHARMINDER, check the codes at [swap last 'End if' with the following 'END'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c445de/2)

Comment: @Sphinx I have compiled the procedure mentioned in the fiddle, it gives compile time error
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
   END LOOP' at line 35

Comment: @DHARMINDER, sorry, missed the last two lines when copied. please try again.

Comment: @Sphinx Now it gives the error 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT *  FROM salary1;

   
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FET' at line 10

Answer (score 0):

Well you asked for an answer without `JOIN`, but that seemed arbitrary, so here's an answer with `JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    sums1.id
    , S1Sum + S2Sum AS SalarySum 
FROM (SELECT id, SUM(CAST(salary AS int)) AS S1Sum
      FROM salary1 
      GROUP BY id) sums1
JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(CAST(salary AS int)) AS S2Sum
      FROM salary2
      GROUP BY id) sums2 
ON sums1.id = sums2.id
```

I am guessing your performance is bad because all of your columns are `varchar` when they should be `int` or `numeric`. But we don't have much to go on so hopefully this helps you come to a solid solution.

Also the post was edited to add both MySQL and Oracle tags so it's difficult to determine what the syntax should be...

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i need to implement this without using join